# Cannot fetch values from dynamically created textboxes in javascript

Tags: javascript

[FORM SNAPSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIz2W.jpg)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYqlb.jpg)PHP code for creating textboxes dynamically

```
for($i=0;$i<count($chkSelec);$i++)
            {
                echo "<td align='center'><input type='text' id='".$columnValue[$i]."' name='".$columnValue[$i]."[]' size='5' onchange=AddToAggr('".$columnValue[$i]."',".$count_var.") required /></td>";   
            }

echo "<td align='center'><input type='text' id='Aggr' name='Aggr[]' size='7' value='".$rowText['TotalGrade']."' readonly='readonly' disabled/></td>";
```

This is my javascript function

```
var i=0;
var TotalGrade=0;
function AddToAggr(val,countvar) {
    var group6 = document.PIScoreForm.Aggr;
    for(var i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for(var j=i;j<countvar;j++)
        {
            if(val=='Comm')
            {       
                var group1 = document.PIScoreForm.Comm;
                 TotalGrade += parseFloat(group1[i].value);
            }
            else if(val=='PresSkil')    
            {
                var group2 = document.PIScoreForm.PresSkil;
                TotalGrade += parseFloat(group2[i].value);
                alert('2 :'+TotalGrade);
            }
            else
            {
                    TotalGrade += 0;
            }
        }   
        document.getElementsByName("Aggr")[i].value = TotalGrade;
        alert("Total " + i+" "+TotalGrade); 
    }
}
```

I want to find average of each column and display it in Aggr textbox. in first for loop ,the condition i<2 is number of Panalist. I hard-coded the value for time-being.

Comment: Since this is all about html/javascript, please provide the html output of your php.

Comment: I added output snapshot

Answer (score 0):

For starters the **document.getElementsByName** call should accept '**Aggr[]**' and not 'Aggr' that will remove the "not an object" errors being throw on the console.

Without having additional context there may be additional changes required, here's that fix applied to what you've provided.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PHP code for creating textboxes dynamically</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
// Mock Data
$rowText = array (
    'TotalGrade' => 0
);
$columnValue = array();
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
    $columnValue[$i] = "testValue";
    echo "<td align='center'><input type='text' id='".$columnValue[$i]."' name='".$columnValue[$i]."[]' size='5' onchange=AddToAggr('".$columnValue[$i]."',".$i.") required /></td>";
}

echo "<td align='center'><input type='text' id='Aggr' name='Aggr[]' size='7' value='".$rowText['TotalGrade']."' readonly='readonly' disabled/></td>";

?>

<script>
    var i=0;
    var TotalGrade=0;
    function AddToAggr(val,countvar) {
        //var group6 = document.PIScoreForm.Aggr;
        for(var i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            for(var j=i;j<countvar;j++)
            {
                if(val=='Comm')
                {
                    var group1 = document.PIScoreForm.Comm;
                    TotalGrade += parseFloat(group1[i].value);
                }
                else if(val=='PresSkil')
                {
                    var group2 = document.PIScoreForm.PresSkil;
                    TotalGrade += parseFloat(group2[i].value);
                    alert('2 :'+TotalGrade);
                }
                else
                {
                    TotalGrade += 0;
                }
            }
            document.getElementsByName("Aggr[]")[i].value = TotalGrade;
            alert("Total " + i+" "+TotalGrade);
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```